# What is the feature called that allows users to set specific alert settings per notification type

Tags: ios

I noticed that for most iOS apps you can only change notification settings (Banners, Sounds, Badges) with the scope of the entire app from Settings. But a few iOS apps, e.g. TV and Calendar it is possible to change notification settings for different notification "types" (don't know the correct term).

For example, under Settings->Notifications->TV you can see two "types":

- Up Next
- New Features

For each of these "types" of notifications, you can independently disable notifications or disable sound or badges.

I have tried to find documentation of this, but I could not find any documents suggesting that this is linked to either the "group" concept or the "category" concept.

What is this feature called and is it available to non-apple developers?

Comment: In this case an image would really help to show what you are referring to. Are you talking about "Customise Notifications" of the apps within the "Notification" settings?

Comment: Tried to edit to make it more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible for external developers.